# Photoshop jsx search and replace text with specific font size for each replace

Tags: javascript, jsx, photoshop, photoshop-script

I am trying to search and replace multiple words in a text layer. Each word in that text layer has a specific font size which is lost during text replacing. Is there a way to replace characters but keep font size? Or maybe replace and set a specific font size?

```
for (var key in keys) {
    var search_name = keys[key];
    var replace_content = key_val_objects[keys[key]];

    for (var j= 0; j < srcDoc.artLayers.length; j++) {
        var lyr = srcDoc.artLayers[j];

        if (lyr.kind == LayerKind.TEXT) {
            var lyr = srcDoc.artLayers[j];
            lyr.textItem.contents = lyr.textItem.contents.replace(search_name, replace_content); 
        }
     }
}
```

What I have so far searched and replaced text but the font size is not preserved. The entire text layer changes to the font size of the first character.

Comment: There's no easy way to do that, here's a starting point though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700236/change-font-for-particular-text-via-script-in-photoshop?r=SearchResults

Comment: I was under the impression that I can set font size for the entire layer, something like ```layer.textItem.size```. Am I wrong?

Comment: For the entire layer yes, but your question was about changing formatting of a specific part of a text layer: that's impossible with DOM